# Loading another exe as assembly and creating its startup object (main form). Is that possible?

Tags: c#, .net, exe, .net-assembly

I have a program written in .net language. I don't have sources for it.
I added it to my program as assembly and all is fine unless I try to create it's main form:

```
GCRebuilder.MainForm main_wnd = new GCRebuilder.MainForm();
```

Here I getting exception `FileNotFoundexception.`
`Unable to load a file or assembly "gcr, Version=1.0.3480.29421, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" or one of it's dependencies. Unable to find specified file.`
That program that I trying to load is a single exe only.

It there anything can be done or this is waste of time?
I need this to use program functionality through invoking needed for me methods of main form.

Comment: Look in the the _fusion log_ to see what it doesn't find.

Comment: @Jester - sorry, could you tell what is this? I don't know about something like that exist.

Comment: See the [msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4.aspx). You can also enable it using the registry and open the text log files yourself. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255669/how-to-enable-assembly-bind-failure-logging-fusion-in-net).

Comment: Make it as answer about fusion log. I were able to do so and found out that exe had different name than my program attempts to load. I changed it and now can create main form fine enough. Well, I can't display it because of unknown Null Reference exception, but I think this is different story.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check DotPeek (free software) for viewing the source code of the assembly.

Comment: This is unbelievable! This thing decompiled exe and made solution that compiled and started just after a few error fixes!